# Loading an Array Elements with a PHP variable

Tags: php, windows, xampp

Hello There I'm having a problem creating an array

```
<?php
 //I'm actually grabbing the list from MySQl
 //$list = '"02","03"';
 $friends_list_array = array($list);
 echo $friends_list_array[0];
?>
```

This is the Code !
But It Doesn't Work

Expected Result : `02`

Output what i got from above code : `"02","03"`

Someone help please ?

Comment: don't you think expected result need to be:- `"02"`

Comment: Is `$list` your input, or why don't you initialize it directly as an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [php explode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):-

```
<?php
  $list = '"02","03"';
  $friends_list_array = explode(",",$list);
  echo $friends_list_array[0];
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/839531

***If you want output strictly  `02`:-***

```
<?php
  $list = '"02","03"';
  $friends_list_array = explode(",",$list);
  echo trim($friends_list_array[0], '"');
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/839537

Comment: I think adding `trim` to this will provide exact OP's need: `trim($friends_list_array[0], "\"")` : https://eval.in/839535

Comment: @Thamilan  added that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try also this way:-

```
<?php
$friends_list_array = array(
    "02",
    "03"
);

echo $friends_list_array[0];
```

Comment: you completely changed the input structure what OP provided (he gave string and you are telling him to manually make it to array initially)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Sorry about that. But maybe OP can try this way for his case or maybe he can learn something by see it a different way. :)